# EF Database first - Adding new models to existing ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

So I have a database and have created a model from it. Everything works just fine. But now I want to add more tables to my database and produce models from them.

Is that possible with EF Database first? Do I have to recreate all models for it to add new ones? All tables are of course from same database.

Example:
Let's say I have `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3`.
And by using `DBContextGenerator` in VS I've generated models from `.edmx` file. So I'd have `Model1`, `Model2`, and `Model3` for corresponding database tables, and I'd like to add `Table4` and `Model4`.

Do I have to recreate everything or is it possible to add somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up your .edmx in design view.
Right click in there somewhere and choose "Update Model from Database".
On the "Add" tab, expand "Tables", and find your new database tables.
Check them, and click finish.

I've done this regularly as the DB changes and tables are added during development, it's been very reliable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it immediately!

Comment: For me this doesn't generate the classes. any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you didn't refresh / rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

To generate the classes, do the following:

1. Right click on the .tt file of the solution explorer.
2. Click on the "Run custom tool".
3. Click on "OK" for the warning.
4. new classes will be generated.